# API for Creating/Editing Google Slides

Tags: google-slides-api

Does Google offer a REST or Javascript API for creating and editing slides?  I've been able to figure out how to interact with sheets and most of the other services offered as part of Docs/Drive, but haven't had any luck with Slides.

If there is no API, I'd be willing to create files directly myself, but I haven't been able to find any documentation on a Slides file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/) was launched on 11/9/2016. It provides the ability to read, create, and edit Google Slides presentations.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into this too. Looks like it's been a requested feature since at least 2012, follow [Issue Tracker Link](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1573&q=presentation&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)

Right now the best I know of is to automate making a powerpoint file (e.g. use [this library for python](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) and then upload it to google drive where it will autoconvert. Obviously there are many limitations to this strategy, but in a quick test it worked fine for something simple.

I would also love if Google provided an API that allows making slides like the various API calls for microsoft office.